# Как создать список из вложенных списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки, генераторы

имеется список вида

```
matrix = ['195.123.216.7', '185.100.85.150 | 217.197.83.197', '104.31.72.133 | 104.31.73.133', '136.243.17.41', '148.251.92.78', '104.27.190.41 | 104.27.191.41 | 190.115.26.102']
```

в данный момент с помощью генератора

```
s = [x.split(' | ') if '|' in x else x for x in matrix]
```

я получил следующий выход

```
['195.123.216.7', ['185.100.85.150', '217.197.83.197'], ['104.31.72.133', '104.31.73.133'], '136.243.17.41', '148.251.92.78', ['104.27.190.41', '104.27.191.41', '190.115.26.102']]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно исправить, в генераторе, чтобы выходил список вида `['195.123.216.7', '185.100.85.150', '217.197.83.197', '104.31.72.133', '104.31.73.133', '136.243.17.41', '148.251.92.78', '104.27.190.41', '104.27.191.41', '190.115.26.102']`

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[y.strip() for x in matrix for y in x.split('|')]
```

Comment: спасибо большое полвечера голову ломал)